# SecretValueText returning null value in Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, key-value

I want to retrieve a secret value from key vault in text using powershell. To achieve this I am using:

`(Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'vault_name' -Name 'secret_name').SecretValueText`

But for some reason this is returing null value. What am I doing wrong and how to overcome this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below cmdlet, to retrieve the key vault secret from PowerShell  as suggested in [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-powershell#retrieve-a-secret-from-key-vault).

```
Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName <vaultName> -Name <secretName> -AsPlainText
```

Here is the reference screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I already found another way to do this but your approach is even simpler than what I implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to convert the secret value to plain text using Powershell which worked for me:

```
$fetch=(Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'vault_name' -Name 'secret_name')
$value=$fetch.SecretValue
$BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($value)            
$PlainPassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)            
Write-Host $PlainPassword
```